# I want to check for a specific element in a sublist and remove repeated sublists with the same element in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, unique

i have this

```
lst = [['100','LA'],['101','NY'],['100','NC']]
lst2 = []
```

i need to check if there's any 100,101,etc repeated and remove the repeated numbers. So the second list would look like this

```
lst2=[['100','LA'],['101','NY']]
```

because the 100 was already added once in that second list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to do this is using a generic *uniqueness* filter:

```
def uniqueness(iterable,key=lambda x:x):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:
        fitem = key(item)
        if fitem not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(fitem)
```

You can then use it like:

```
list2 = list(uniqueness(lst,key=lambda x:x[0]))
```

If you do not specify, the filter will assume the entire element (but this will fail here, because `list` is not hashable).

Comment: it worked perfectly, thanks. I don't actually need the code to be efficient so it's ok :D

Answer (score 0):

An answer without lambda's.

```
nmbrs = [n for n, city in lst] 

lst2 = [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x[0] not in nmbrs[:i]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.